# Why TypeScript does not infer types of input arguments

Tags: typescript

I have this code example in TypeScript:

```
function twice(x:number) {
   return x*2;
}

function calltwice(y) {
   return twice(y);
}
```

It compiles and execution in node gives NaN.

I am wondering why type of y is any? I expected it to be inferred as number because it is passed to twice function which can take only number. And this expectation was basically caused by F#:

```
let twice x = x*2
let calltwice y = twice y
```

who exactly knows that calltwice is int->int

Comment: Your callstack starts at `calltwice` and `y` argument is inferred as any. Within that `twice(y)` call does not throw any error only because `y` is of type any. I guess you are trying to look at it the other way around. You just have to specify type for y @ `function calltwice(y:number)..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify argument and return type:

```
function twice(x: number): number {
   return x*2;
}

function calltwice(y: number): number {
   return twice(y);
}
```

In this case compiler will check types during compilation.

***Note:*** Typescript compiles into JavaScript, and during execution it will not check types at all. So potentially (if you will call this code from JavaScript) you can pass any object to these functions.

Comment: Small addition, calltwice return type could also be dynamically determined using the expression `ReturnType<typeof twice>`